# How to change Date format value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this date value `2020-03-04 03:02:26`. But I just want to convert it into `March 4, 2020 - 03:02` on a particular display. I can do this in `PHP` but I can't solve it in `JavaScript`. I hope everyone can help me. Thanks in advance :)

```
var curr_date = value.date_payment /* Current Date and Time value 2020-03-04 03:02:26 */

var final_date = "March 4, 2020 - 03:02"; /* My Desired Output */
```

Comment: Try something - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to transform dates is with a library such as Day.js (https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs), Moment (https://momentjs.com/) or js-joda (https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/).

You can use it to format the date:

```
const today = moment(value.date_payment);
console.log(today.format('LLLL'));
```

There are a wide variety of formatting options, Day.js is only 2kb big and a simple transformation like the above makes your code easier to read.

Comment: A 52KB library just for that?

Comment: Depends how much he needs to do with dates but I said easiest not smallest filesize, use day.js if size is a concern: https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has no built-in function to format dates; you need to do it manually.

Here's a solution:

```js
const monthNameMap = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

const date = new Date;
const formattedDate = `${monthNameMap[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getDate()}, ${date.getFullYear()} - ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`;

console.log(formattedDate)
```

Comment: This idea is not solve my problem. I just want to get the same value of Date, not the current date. But anyway thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can set the `date` variable to any date object.